# Toshiba laptop screen all white

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, lcd

I have a Toshiba Satellite laptop here, about four years old. my oldest took it to school and ever since then, the computer boots into Ububntu OK but the LCD screen is all white - no image.

I can see what's on the screen by plugging it into an external monitor and everything works from there. I'm typing this in on the laptop now. We thought this made it seem like the LCD panel needed to be replaced so we got a new one and installed it tonight, but it too shows just a plain white screen.

This doesn't sound like an inverter problem, since the screen is not dark, right?

Can there be a problem on the motherboard that affects the LCD panel (OK, technically it's a CCFL) but not the external monitor VGA port?

If this is about the cable that feeds the signal into the LCD panel, is there any way to trouble shoot or test that?

Thanks for any other ideas...

Answer (score 0):

Power to the screen and the LVDS video signal both go from the laptop to the screen via the same cable so evidently that cable is not unplugged on the laptop side as the screen is lit. So it is possible that the LVDS cable is disconnected on the panel side.